# Meta Box Not Saving Content

Tags: wordpress

The meta box does not save its content, but that content shows up on page. When editing that page, the meta box is empty and its content is lost. Here's my code:

```
/*
 * Custom meta boxes 
 */

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'create_meta_boxes' );

function create_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', __('Additional information'), 'meta_box_info', 'Post', 'normal', 'low' );
}


// Create meta box: Additional information

function meta_box_info( $post ) {

    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
?>

    <textarea name="meta_box_info" id="meta_box_info" style="width: 100%; margin: 6px 0;" /><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>

<?php   
}

// Save meta box: Additional information

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_meta_box_info' );
function save_meta_box_info( $post_id ) {

    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags
            'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
        )
    );

    if( isset( $_POST['meta_box_info'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_box_info', wp_kses( $_POST['meta_box_info'], $allowed ) );

    $chk = ( isset( $_POST['meta_box_info_rotation'] ) && $_POST['meta_box_info_rotation'] ) ? 'on' : 'off';

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_box_info_rotation', $chk );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this line before Textarea

```
<?php $text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_box_info', true); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did the trick, amazing!

Do you have any idea how I can stop the meta box from removing paragraphs and line breaks? Or add the visual editor to it?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor was by far the easiest method I found for adding editor to textarea.

Comment: I tried that just now, but I couldn't get it to work:

`add_action( 'edit_form_advanced', 'my_second_editor' );
function my_second_editor() {
 wp_editor( $content, 'meta_box_info' );
}`

Comment: just add `wp_editor( $text, 'meta_box_info' );` instead to textarea
`<textarea name="meta_box_info" id="meta_box_info" style="width: 100%; margin: 6px 0;" /><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>`  In your original above code

Comment: Sorry to be such a dork and waste your time, but where exactly do you mean? I tried locating the place to put that code in but failed in my attempt.

Comment: see your meta_box_info function just replace your previous function with following function.


`// Create meta box: Additional information

function meta_box_info( $post ) {

    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );

    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );

   $text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_box_info', true); 

   wp_editor( $text, 'meta_box_info' );
  
}`

Comment: I did that, here: http://pastebin.com/tSWXh6Vf

The editor appears, but changes are not saved (bolding of text) and are not shown in the post either.

Comment: Can you please add this `wp_editor( $text, 'meta_box_info',
$settings = array('textarea_name'=>'meta_box_info') );` Instead of `wp_editor( $text, 'meta_box_info' );` and check it once.

Comment: I did that, but it still doesn't save the bold or paragraphs.

Comment: Finally, I gave up and used a plugin. Thanks.